# Should paypal data be encrypted before it's stored?

Tags: security, encryption, paypal, paypal-ipn

Just to clarify, I'm not talking about PayPal buttons here.

I'm referring to response data I receive when making API calls including IPN.
The response data I'm looking to store includes transaction IDs, payKeys and various amounts.
No passwords, CC numbers and the like.

If my database was compromised, would an attacker be able to use this data against my clients?

I'm asking this specifically about the PayPal response data because I don't want to encrypt everything just for the sake of encrypting, it will tremendously hurt my search capabilities.

Is there a standard (even something publicly posted by PayPal) on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking about PCI Compliance. Here is the information directly from the PayPal Developer Site: 
[PCI Compliance Information from PayPal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment)

**Important**: You are responsible for processing card industry (PCI) compliance for protecting cardholder data. For example, storing the Card Security Code (CSC) violates PCI compliance. For more information about PCI compliance, see  [PCI Security Standards Council](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org)

Since you already know about [IPNS](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), I will just have the link to it on here to help you.

In answer to your question, if you have a server that holds any customer data that is considered sensitive per the PCI Security Standards Council, the information must be encrypted. If it is not sensitive data, like your own personal order numbers, then you do not need to encrypt the data.

Comment: I think he's asking a simpler question. At least I am. Is there anything in a Paypal IPN message that should be encrypted? as per PCI or any other standard?

Comment: I'm not talking about PCI here, or about TLS for that matter. I already have the IPN response data in my hands, now you're asking me to consider whether this data is sensitive and should it be encrypted, but *that is exactly what I'm asking here.* How sensitive it this *specific* data? Should it be encrypted?